# In-App Purchase buyers list with order Id

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I do use In-App Purchase in my app. I just want to get list of all buyers name, date-time and other information related to order.

How do I get it from iTunes Connect ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't get the purchaser's details. You can get the date that items that were purchased from the sales reports in AppStoreConnect. If you want to know the time that purchases are made then you would need to log it on your own server when the purchase is completed in your app.

Comment: Hi @Paulw11

Thanks for quick reply.

I just want to get order id from the receipt. So is it possible to get order id of each purchases from iTunes Connect ? I want to make sales report  with order id.